# Error al leer con QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy usando qdatastream para leer datos binarios desde un stream. Bueno el código basicamente que implemente es el siguiente:

```
QFile *archivoStub;
archivoStub = new QFile();
archivoStub->setFileName(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
archivoStub->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
/* Leer los datos de la trama*/
QDataStream in(&archivoStub);
QString trama;
qint32 a;
```

El problema esta en que cuando leo los datos me muestra el siguiente error:

> el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'QFile **' a 'QIODevice *' Los
>   tipos se¤alados no est n relacionados; la conversi¢n requiere
>   reinterpret_cast, conversi¢n de estilo de C o conversi¢n de estilo de
>   funci¢n

Mi pregunta es primero este error de compilación a que se debe? Y segundo, que mi fichero contendrá varios ejecutables, una trama de datos y un entero que define el tamaño de mi trama de datos. ¿Hay alguna manera de serializar estos datos para que sean facilmente legible.

Cuando digo serializar me refiero:

> Si con qdatastream puedo ordenar varios elementos y leerlos. Luego
>   también si uso qdatastream y hay otro tipo contenido como ficheros
>   podría leer mi serie o si no es posible tendría que implementarlo todo
>   con qdatastream.

El código por si todavía no entendeis a que me refiero.
Junto varios ficheros:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect (ui->botonExaminar1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(examinar1()));
    connect (ui->botonExaminar2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(examinar2()));
    connect (ui->botonUnir,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(juntar()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::examinar1()
{
    ui->ejecutable1Texto->setText(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Abrir archivo"));
}
void MainWindow::examinar2()
{
    ui->ejecutable2Texto->setText(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Abrir archivo"));
}
void MainWindow::juntar()
{
    /** función para juntar los dos ejecutables **/

    /* declaraciones */
    QFile archivoSalida;
    QFile *archivoEjecutable1;
    QFile *archivoEjecutable2;
    QFile *archivoStub;
    QByteArray tamano1;
    QByteArray tamano2;
    QByteArray tamano3;
    QByteArray trama;
    QString nombreEjecutable1;
    QString nombreEjecutable2;

    /* inicializaciones */
    archivoEjecutable1 = new QFile();
    archivoEjecutable2 = new QFile();
    archivoStub = new QFile();

    /* establecer nombres de los ficheros */
    archivoSalida.setFileName(QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Archivo de salida"));
    archivoEjecutable1->setFileName(ui->ejecutable1Texto->text());
    archivoEjecutable2->setFileName(ui->ejecutable2Texto->text());
    archivoStub->setFileName("stubb.exe");

    /* abrir ficheros */
    archivoSalida.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    archivoEjecutable1->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    archivoEjecutable2->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    archivoStub->open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    /* escribir en el fichero de salida los tres ejecutables */
    archivoSalida.write(archivoStub->readAll() + archivoEjecutable1->readAll() + archivoEjecutable2->readAll());

    /* Convertir los tamaños a QString */
    tamano1.setNum(archivoStub->size());
    tamano2.setNum(archivoEjecutable1->size());
    tamano3.setNum(archivoEjecutable2->size());

    /* Cojer los nombres de los ejecutables */
    nombreEjecutable1 = archivoEjecutable1->fileName().split(QDir::separator()).last();
    nombreEjecutable2 = archivoEjecutable2->fileName().split(QDir::separator()).last();

    /* Crear la trama de datos */
    trama = tamano1 + "|@|" + tamano2 + "|@|" + tamano3 + "|@|" + nombreEjecutable1.toLatin1() + "|@|" + nombreEjecutable2.toLatin1();

    /* Escribir la trama con su tamaño correspondiente */
    QDataStream out(&archivoSalida);
    out << trama;   // serialize a qbytearray
    out << trama.size();        // serialize an integer

    /* Escribir la trama en el archivo de salida */
    //archivoSalida.write(trama,trama.size());

    /* Cerrar todos los ficheros */
    archivoEjecutable1->close();
    archivoEjecutable2->close();
    archivoStub->close();
}
```

Intento leer los datos:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <QDir>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QProcess>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QDir directorio;
    QFile *archivoStub;
    QFile *archivoEjecutable1;
    QFile *archivoEjecutable2;
    //QString trama;
    QString tamano1;
    QString tamano2;
    QString tamano3;
    QString nombre1;
    QString nombre2;
    archivoStub = new QFile();
    archivoEjecutable1 = new QFile(QDir::tempPath());
    archivoEjecutable2 = new QFile(QDir::tempPath());
    archivoStub->setFileName(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
    archivoStub->open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    /* Leer los datos de la trama*/
    QDataStream in(&archivoStub);
    QString trama;
    qint32 a;

    archivoStub->seek(archivoStub->size() - a);
    trama = archivoStub->read(a);


    tamano1 = trama.split("|@|")[0];
    tamano2 = trama.split("|@|")[1];
    tamano3 = trama.split("|@|")[2];
    nombre1 = trama.split("|@|")[3];
    nombre2 = trama.split("|@|")[4];

    archivoEjecutable1->setFileName(directorio.tempPath()+"/"+nombre1);
    archivoEjecutable2->setFileName(directorio.tempPath()+"/"+nombre2);

    archivoEjecutable1->open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    archivoEjecutable2->open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    archivoStub->seek(tamano1.toInt());
    archivoEjecutable1->write(archivoStub->read(tamano2.toInt()));
    archivoStub->seek(tamano1.toInt() + tamano2.toInt());
    archivoEjecutable2->write(archivoStub->read(tamano3.toInt()));
    archivoEjecutable1->close();
    archivoEjecutable2->close();

    QProcess::startDetached(directorio.tempPath() +"/"+nombre1);
    QProcess::startDetached(directorio.tempPath() +"/"+nombre2);


}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo.

```
QFile *archivoStub; // PUNTERO A QFILE
archivoStub = new QFile();
archivoStub->setFileName(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
archivoStub->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
/* Leer los datos de la trama*/
QDataStream in(&archivoStub); // PUNTERO A PUNTERO A QFILE
```

En lugar de `QDataStream in( &archivoStub )`, haz

```
QDataStream in( archivoStub );
```

El error es auto-explicativo: no se puede convertir un **puntero a puntero a** en un **puntero a**.

No entiendo la segunda parte de tu pregunta, la verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de solucionar el error pasa por evitar la memoria dinámica, ya que en este caso la misma no es necesaria:

```
QFile archivoStub;
archivoStub.setFileName(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
archivoStub.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
/* Leer los datos de la trama*/
QDataStream in(&archivoStub);
```

En mi opinión siempre es preferible evitar la memoria dinámica ya que la misma suele ser más lenta y nos obliga a realizar una gestión adicional de los recursos.

En cuanto a lo que comentas sobre serializar los datos para que sean fácilmente leibles... ¿te refieres a un lector humano o una máquina?

Si te refieres al primer caso, considera el uso de XML. En el caso de que el lector sea una máquina puedes optar por json, protocol buffers, xdr, ... Se usan principalmente para comunicaciones, pero nada impide almacenar un json en un fichero. La ventaja de estos formatos es que suelen necesitar menos espacio para almacenar la misma información.

Comment: era si simplemente con qdatastream podía ordenar varios elementos y leerlos. Luego también si uso qdatastream y hay otro tipo contenido como ficheros podría leer mi serie o sino era posible tendría que implementarlo todo con qdatastream.